# Boxplot what do the dots represent?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I am learning datascience for data analysis I am using seaborn and doing a box plot which resulted in below plot

[image]

I understood the whiskers which represting quantiles and the dots on top at 45 and 52 are max values. what I don't understand is what do the dots in between represent and what are they called

Comment: ["The box shows the quartiles of the dataset while the whiskers extend to show the rest of the distribution, except for points that are determined to be “outliers” using a method that is a function of the inter-quartile range."](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In box plots, dots are outliers. This is not particular to Seaborn or any other tool; it is generical to visualization in statistics.

The outliers are points that stay out of the interval `[Q1-1.5*IQR; Q3+1.5*IQR]`, with:

- `Q1 = Quartile 1 (25th percentile)`
- `Q3 = Quartile 3 (75th percentile)`
- `IQR = Interquartile range from Q1 to Q3`

I think you will understand that better if you plot the histograms matching those box plots :)

Please, read this [post](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/plots/python-boxplot/), it is quite good :)

Comment: Link gives 401 error (deleted apparently)

Comment: true, thanks! So, I would recommend this one: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/plots/python-boxplot/

I'll update the answer to lead to this post instead